# Alternative Definition For A Prime

Tags: prime-numbers, definition

The standard definition of a prime that we all learned is: an integer which is divisible only by itself and one. Additionally, we exclude $\pm1$ from being a prime now a days (though this hasn't always been the case) despite the similarities with primes in this defining trait.

Making a special exception for $\pm1$ feels a bit arbitrary, and leads to confusion; at least among lay people. Instead, I propose the following equivalent definition:

> An integer p is said to be a **prime** if and only if p is coprime to all integers except for multiples of p.

This excludes $\pm1$ since $\pm1$ is coprime to all integers, including its multiples. And it of course excludes composites since a composite c will not be coprime to its prime factors. But the prime factors are not a multiple of c, and thus c is not prime. This definition also works for the negative primes, since a prime $p$ is a multiple of $-p$ and visa versa.

Are there any problems with this definition? Are there any better/more useful ones out there? Thoughts?

EDIT:

> Two integers x and y are said to be **coprime** if and only if $\gcd(x, y) = 1$.

Comment: Well, the only "real" way (for me) to define primes is in the ring $\mathbb Z$, in the context of ring theory. Since $\Bbb Z$ is a principal ideal domain, primes and irreducibles coincide - and the *naive definition* of prime numbers exactly coincides with that of irreducible elements in the ring $\Bbb Z$. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_element.

Comment: @esoteric-elliptic Hmm - it looks like my definition of a prime would work there too, with the additional qualification that you are talking about elements in a commutative  ring. I like the generalization :)

Comment: You would need *coprime* defined for your proposal, which will involve a divisor other than $\pm1$ so not much simplification. Teaching with the natural numbers (so ignoring $\pm$), my understanding is that a common definition is that a prime has precisely two divisors, $1$ and itself.

Comment: @Henry I've gone ahead and added the definition of **coprime** above. While this definition does require a little number theory, I would argue it's simple to understand, concise, and doesn't require a list of exceptions.

Comment: I think pedagogically the proposed definition is cumbersome. Imagine a grade school student learning these things. The "old" definition (or equivalently, something like "the only way to write $p = a b$ (in the natural numbers) is $a = 1, b = p$ or vice versa") is easily manipulated by trying to arrange blocks, drawing little trees where you try to break out twos or threes etc.; this new definition requires both a conceptual leap of comparing the factors of integers (or are we teaching them the Euclidean algorithm?)...

Comment: ... and on top of that requires them to check infinitely many things, or else think deeply about why it suffices to only check up to $p$.

Comment: @prets That is fair, this wouldn't be as accessible as an entry level definition. Although I don't think it would require going as far as teaching the Euclidean Algorithm necessarily; one can understand what a factor is and what the greatest common factor is without knowing that algorithm :)

Comment: Sure, but my point is that at that point have you not just essentially recovered the old definition, which hence is conceptually simpler?

Comment: @prets For someone who is just being introduced to these concepts, I would agree that the old definition is easier to grasp. However, for someone who has studied a little number I would argue that it ceases to be easier to understand and is simply more tedious and less concise.

Comment: Not sure I agree. Having taught undergraduate number theory many times, I think (a) there's an advantage in retaining the definitions students are used to (so long as they're not somehow wrong) and (b) in practice why primality is useful in elementary theory, or how it is used, tends to boil down to either knowing it can't be written as a product in very many ways, or else the Euclid's lemma sort of property that if $p \mid a b$, then $p \mid a$ or $p \mid b$. The latter view of course helps bridge the gap to prime ideals in algebra later, too.

Comment: @prets I don't have any experience teaching math to others, so I'll defer to you on what makes for a better pedagogical tool. However, as a long time student of math, I was always aggravated by the need to make what seems to be arbitrary exceptions in this definition. Also in how math classes are taught in general - lots of memorization and regurgitation rather than really developing an understanding of the underlying concepts. Of course, this is the fault of trying to force everyone through at the same rate. I became a math lover as an adult when I studied by myself.

Comment: Your question seems a decent fit for a discussion forum/chatroom, but not great here since it's hard to say what a definitive opinion on the pluses and minuses would be. My 2 cents: if your concern is "The exception for $\pm1$ seems arbitrary", just teach the true history that the exception wasn't always made, and the fact that carving out the exception simplifies unique factorization. This has the side benefit of emphasizing that math definitions are in fact useful choices and not merely magical things from on high.

Comment: @MarkS. Do you have any such forums you could recommend? :) Not familiar with what good math forums are out there.

Comment: Math Stack Exchange has its own chat. There are many different Discord servers for math and many more that happen to have a math channel. There's a bunch of subreddits and some traditional forums with academic/math subforums out there. Quora exists, but might be similarly not compatible with this type of question. Art of Problem Solving has forums. There's Mathstodon on the Mastodon platform. And this is all just in English but there's more in other languages too.

Comment: Thanks @MarkS.  :)

Answer (score 1):

An issue with your definition is that it does not exclude $\pm1$ as you suggest. Expanding the case of 1, for example, we get

> 1 is said to be a prime if and only if 1 is coprime to all integers except for multiples of 1.

But 1 is trivially coprime to all integers in the set {}.

I sympathize with your desire to make the definition of prime more natural, but as written this doesn't get the job done.

---

From your comments below, it appears that you want

> An integer p is said to be a **prime** if and only if p is coprime to all integers except for multiples of p and p is not coprime to any multiple of p.

Unlike your original definition, this is equivalent to the standard definition of a (rational) prime. But I don't know that it feels less like an exception. But that's aesthetics; if you like this one better, go with it!

Comment: $\pm1$ is coprime to 1, which is a multiple of $\pm1$. Thus not prime. In fact, it is coprime to any multiple of 1 - thus in every case failing the definition of a prime.

Comment: @RyanPierceWilliams It sounds like you intended to write something other than "An integer p is said to be a prime if and only if p is coprime to all integers except for multiples of p." If you can figure out what that is, it would help.

Comment: What I wrote is correct, and no one else appears to have not understood it - even if they prefer other definitions. Since 1 is coprime to its multiples then it doesn’t meet the definition

Comment: @RyanPierceWilliams If you need recommendations for a book on logic, I recommend Enderton.

Comment: the problem doesn’t lie with me. But go on and explain how you think 1 would be prime under my provided definition when it would clearly produce a contradiction. The definition says that an integer is prime iff it is coprime to all integers except those that are its multiples. 1 is coprime to all its multiples. Therefore, 1 is not prime.

Comment: @RyanPierceWilliams For 1 to not be "prime" under your definition, you would need to have an integer $n$ which is not a multiple of 1 and which is not coprime to 1. There is no such integer.

Comment: By comparison, consider the case of 4. For it to not be "prime" in your definition, there would need to be some number $n$, not a multiple of 4, such that $n$ and 4 are not coprme. But 6 is such a number, hence 4 is not "prime".

Comment: that is simply incorrect. For an integer to not be prime, by the definition I provided, you need to show that it is either coprime to a multiple of p (as w 1), or else show that there exists an integer not coprime to p which is not a multiple of p (2 in the case of 4). You missed the prior case and that is why you are having trouble.

Comment: @RyanPierceWilliams The negation of "p is coprime to a multiple of p or there exists an integer not coprime to p which is not a multiple of p" is "p is coprime to all integers except for multiples of p and p is not coprime to any multiple of p", not "p is coprime to all integers except for multiples of p". I've edited my answer in case you intended the former rather than the latter.

Comment: what I wrote is perfectly correct and equivalent to your more verbose version. Saying that “p is coprime to all integers except multiples of p” necessarily excludes p from being coprime with its multiples. Though I am curious what “except multiples of p” means in your head? Is English not your first language?

Comment: @RyanPierceWilliams "x is coprime to all integers except for multiples of y" means that, for any n in the set Z \ y*Z, n is coprime to x.

Comment: except means that you are excluding those values from being coprime altogether. If someone said “the odd numbers are all the integers except those which are multiples of 2” - only you would think that multiples of two are odd. Notice that nobody else who read and replied to this thread had any trouble understanding the definition.